# Decomposing a representation of $S_{3}$ over the vector space $\mathbb{F}_{2}[\{1,2,3\}]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, representation-theory

Given the usual action of $S_{3}$ on $X:=\{1,2,3\}$, consider the linearization to obtain a representation of $S_{3}$ on $\mathbb{F}_{2}[X]$ (where $\mathbb{F}_{2}$ is the field with 1 element). Determine whether this representation is decomposable as a direct sum of irreducible representations (if not, explain why, if so, give the explicit decomposition).

We can encode each vector as, $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)$ where $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{F}_{2}$, and for example: $(1,2) ~ \cdot ~ (\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3) = (\alpha_2,\alpha_1,\alpha_3)$. We know that the augmentation submodule always exist and is irreducible of degree $2$, where:
$$I = \{(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3) \in \mathbb{F}_{2}^{3}: \alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + \alpha_3 = 0 \}.$$
We then have that:
$$V = \mathbb{F}_{2}\{ (1,1,1)\},$$
is a $S_{3}$ invariant subspace, and irreducible since it is of degree $1$ (spanned by one vector). So then we have that,

$$\mathbb{F}_{2}S_{3} = V \oplus I.$$

Is my proof correct? Any issues. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know why you write $\mathbb{F}_2S_3$: surely that would be the $6$-dimensional regular representation. Nor do I understand why you write $\mathbb{F}_2[X]$, surely that is the polynomial ring on the symbols lying in $X$; surely you just want the $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space with basis $X$? But the module you want is indeed the direct sum of the two modules you describe.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Hello, again, and thanks for the help. How else would one write the "module", I'm using the notation from Dummit and Foote here and I wanted to write $FG$ module, so that is what I was going for here.

Comment: I don't have a copy of that book so I can't see exactly what notation is used.